# NIntegrate: Random occurence of "Catastrophic loss of precision" error

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have the following integral:

```
kernel[x_, xp_, phi_, d_] := 2 Sqrt[x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[phi]] - 2 Sqrt[d^2 + x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[phi]] - 1/2 d (Log[x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[phi]] + Log[-d + Sqrt[d^2 + x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[phi]]] - 3 Log[d + Sqrt[d^2 + x^2 + xp^2 - 2 x xp Cos[phi]]])
divM[x_,x0_] := (-1+(4 Sinh[x]^2)/(Cosh[2 x]+Cosh[2 x0])) (Sech[x-x0]+Sech[x + x0])+4/x Cosh[x0] Sinh[x]/(Cosh[2 x]+Cosh[2 x0])
Iv[x0_,d_] := NIntegrate[x xp divM[x,x0] divM[xp,x0] kernel[x,xp,phi,d], {x,0,Infinity}, {xp,0,Infinity}, {phi,0,Pi}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 1000000}, MaxRecursion -> 20]
```

Or, in a human readable form:

$k(\varrho,\varrho^\prime,\phi,\delta)=-2 \sqrt{\delta ^2+\varrho ^2-2 \varrho  \varrho^\prime \cos (\phi)+\varrho^{\prime 2}}+2 \sqrt{\varrho ^2-2 \varrho  \varrho^\prime \cos (\phi)+\varrho^{\prime 2}}-\frac{1}{2} \delta  \Big[\log \left(\sqrt{\delta ^2+\varrho ^2-2 \varrho  \varrho^\prime \cos (\phi)+\varrho^{\prime 2}}-\delta \right)-3 \log \left(\sqrt{\delta ^2+\varrho ^2-2 \varrho  \varrho^\prime \cos (\phi)+\varrho^{\prime 2}}+\delta \right)+\log \left(\varrho ^2-2 \varrho  \varrho^\prime \cos (\phi)+\varrho^{\prime 2}\right)\Big]$

$\partial_\varrho(\varrho m_r(\varrho))= \frac{4 \cosh (\rho_0) \sinh (\varrho )}{\cosh (2 \rho_0)+\cosh (2 \varrho )}+\varrho \left[\frac{1}{\cosh(\varrho-\rho_0)}+\frac{1}{\cosh(\varrho+\rho_0)}\right] \left(\frac{4 \sinh ^2(\varrho )}{\cosh (2 \rho_0)+\cosh (2 \varrho )}-1\right)$

$I_v = \int_0^\infty d \varrho \int_0^\infty d \varrho^\prime \int_0^{\pi} d \phi \, \partial_\varrho(\varrho m_r(\varrho)) \partial_{\varrho^\prime}(\varrho^\prime m_r(\varrho^\prime)) k(\varrho,\varrho^\prime,\phi,\phi^\prime,\delta)$

Now my problem is that the function `Iv` fails to evaluate at random values of `x0`, for instance for `x0=50`. The error message is

`Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral.`

Increasing the working precision has no effect. Also, there is no problem evaluating the integral for `x0=40` or `x0=60`.

Any ideas what might cause this issue?

Also, for large values of `x0>200`, the integral fails when I use integer values for `x0` (for instance `Iv[1000,1]`) and calculates without complaint, but to a wrong value, for floating point values (i.e., `Iv[1000.,1]`). Here, I am particularly worried about the wrong result that comes without a warning.

**Edit:**

As suggested in the comments, I tried evaluating the integral without the extra options, i.e.,

```
It[x0_,d_] := NIntegrate[x xp divM[x,x0] divM[xp,x0] kernel[x,xp,phi,d], {x,0,Infinity}, {xp,0,Infinity}, {phi,0,Pi}]
```

For `x0=50`, both `It[50.,1]` and `Iv[50.,1]` fail to evaluate. At `x0=40`, both evaluate, but yield very different results:

`Iv[40.,1] = 16.86`

`It[40.,1] = 89.60`

where the latter also says

`The global error of the strategy GlobalAdaptive has increased more 
than 2000 times. The global error is expected to decrease 
monotonically after a number of integrand evaluations. Suspect one of 
the following: the working precision is insufficient for the 
specified precision goal; the integrand is highly oscillatory or it 
is not a (piecewise) smooth function; or the true value of the 
integral is 0. Increasing the value of the GlobalAdaptive option 
MaxErrorIncreases might lead to a convergent numerical integration. 
NIntegrate obtained 89.5960211577929 and 0.008059953558893987 for 
the integral and error estimates.`

Comment: 1. You are requesting a specific integration method, precision goal, etc. Just for kicks and giggles, have you tried to remove all your options and rerun the integration that way? Maybe the problem is in the interaction of two options. 2. Have you tried evaluating the functions in the Iv integrand on their own, to see what their values are when you get that loss of precision? It would help to perhaps pinpoint the origin of the problem.

Comment: For 1, see my edits. For 2: The difference between `x0=40` and `x0=50` is basically that `divM` is shifted by 10 units along the x-axis (in a very good approximation, `divM[x,50] = divM[x-10,40]`. Nothing special happens at `x0=50`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using smaller precision goal when computing with `Iv`, that is why you get a different result. If you increase the `MinRecursion` value you get the same result as with `It`:

```
In[74]:= Clear[Iv]
Iv[x0_, d_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  x xp divM[x, x0] divM[xp, x0] kernel[x, xp, phi, d], {x, 0, 
   Infinity}, {xp, 0, Infinity}, {phi, 0, Pi}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 1000000}, 
  MinRecursion -> 4, MaxRecursion -> 20]

In[76]:= Iv[40., 1]

Out[76]= 89.8663
```

And (only) the message:

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly;
>   suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is
>   0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

Comment: You are right. I was assuming that a precision goal of 3 kind of guarantees that the result is accurate to 3 digits. I came to realize that this is not the case and now always double check if the result of `NIntegrate` (or basically any other computation) is reasonable.